# Can I create a workflow in SP 2013 to create subfolders without using SharePoint designer?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, subfolders

I am trying to create a workflow to auto create subfolders when a new folder is created but I don't have SharePoint Designer. Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to use another way to do it, probably would be via visual studio (or any other workflow tools similar to SP Designer)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible, the available reusable list workflow like

- Publishing Approval workflow.
- Approval workflow.
- Collect Feed Back ...etc

So at least you should have a SharePoint designer or visual studio to achieve your goal.

Once you decide to install SharePoint Designer, you can create a subfolder via SharePoint Designer workflow as mentioned at [Sharepoint Designer subfolder workflow in 11 simple steps](http://www.getinthesky.com/2012/09/sharepoint-designer-2010-subfolder-workflow-in-11-simple-steps/)